# Pull most recent WordPress post's featured image into css as a background-image

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to pull the most recent post's featured image into a div's background css for the top of my site.

I currently have this, which I got from another post on here

```
<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );?>
        <div class="case-hero" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url( $src[0] ); ?>')">
```

Which is pulling the featured image of the current page. Looking for a solution so it finds the most recent.

Any help would be great!
:)

Comment: And doesn't this actually get the last featured image? What does it get?

Comment: It gets the current page's featured image. So this code is on a page called "Portfolio" and it pulls that pages featured image, not the most recent post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$recent = get_posts( array('numberposts' => 10) );
$src = false;
foreach($recent as $p){
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) ){
         $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
         break;
    }
}
if(!$src){
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );   
}
```

This should check last the 10 posts if featured image exists and if found set the $src to that image. If featured image is not found it sets it to this post featured image.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you shuld accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you [search the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts). You can use [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to get the most recent post ID, and then use that to [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Example:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts' => 1,) );
$most_recent_post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent_posts[0]['ID'] );

// Do whatever you want with $most_recent_post_thumbnail
```

Comment: You need to de carefull default setting for wp_get_recent_posts is 'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private', you shuld change it to 'post_status' => 'publish',

Comment: Yep, that's why I linked to the docs. The OP never specified what he/she needed. My code was only a minimal example. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: My knowledge of php is pretty basic, hence why I asked for help. I put what you wrote into my code but it didn't work. I know it's simple to pull the featured image onto a page, but I also need that image to be used as the background-image in the css, not just placed onto the page

Comment: Then you need to hire a coder. Stack Overflow isn't a "find free code" place. It's a place to discuss issues with existing code. The code I posted is a starting point. It won't work out of the box.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thanks for your help